# Calculus regarding Sin and Cos

Tags: calculus, derivatives

When finding the derivative of f(x) and using a "Sin" then the sin becomes "Cos". Sorry it is hard to explain but I will indicate what I am trying to say:

---

f(x) = $sin^3$x = $sinx^3$

f '(x) = $3sinx^2$cosx

---

My question is if it was $cos(x^3)$ why does the answer change to $-3x^2sinx^3$?

What relation does having the the brackets have to do with changing the answer?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, if you plot the functions $f(x) = \sin{x^3}$ and $\sin^3{x}$, they're quite different functions. The derivatives can be calculated by the chain rule of composite functions.

Comment: The brackets also are important in simpler examples such as $100(x + 2)$ versus $(100x) + 2.$ Would you expect those two quantities to be the same? Really the cases where the brackets do **not** matter are the exceptional cases, and we come up with special words such as "associative property of addition" to describe those exceptional cases.

Comment: $sin^{3}x$ is understood to mean $(sin(x))^3$ i.e $sin(x)sin(x)sin(x)$. The expression  $sinx^3$ is ambiguous as it might mean $sin(x^3)$ or the previous $(sin(x))^3$. These have very different meanings.The notation $sin^{3}x$ is an attempt to remove the ambiguity so that $sinx^3$ is assumed to mean $sin(x^3)$. It is not a great notation as $sin^{3}x$ could (should?) mean $sin(sin(sin(x)))$. As always, correct bracketing removes doubts.

Comment: In $100(x + 2)$ versus $(100x) + 2$ the brackets do not tell you to do multiplication. You have to do a multiplication in either case! What the brackets tell you is whether you do the multiplication first or the addition first. Likewise in $\cos(x^3)$ the brackets tell you to cube the $x$ first and then to take the cosine of the result, whereas $\sin^3 x$ is a conventional shorthand for $(\sin x)^3$: you are supposed to take the sine of $x$ first and then cube the result.